# why is std::plus a class template?

Tags: c++

The C++ functor `std::plus` is implemented like

```
template<typename T>
struct plus
{
  constexpr T operator+(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) const
  { return lhs+rhs; }
};
```

but there is also the specialisation

```
template<>
struct plus<void>
{
  template< class T, class U>
  constexpr auto operator()(T&& lhs, U&& rhs) const
  -> decltype(std::forward<T>(lhs) + std::forward<U>(rhs))
  { return    std::forward<T>(lhs) + std::forward<U>(rhs); }
};
```

which has the advantage that it can operate on any types, even differnt ones, as long as `T+U` is defined (for example `std::string` and `const char*`).

I was wondering why `struct std::plus` is not defined as a non-template with the functionality of the existing `std::plus<void>`? Are there any possible applications which could not be served by such an implementation?

Of course, this could have historical reasons (so that it cannot be changed). But if this is the only reason, wouldn't it be possible to change the template argument to default to `void`?

```
template<typename T=void> struct plus;
```

---

edit. I just realised that according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus) `plus<T>` defaults to `plus<void>` since C++14.

---

Arguably, `plus<void>::operator+` could not have been implemented in C98++, but the following could

```
struct plus
{
  template<class T>
  T operator()(const T&lhs, const T&rhs) const
  { return lhs + rhs; }
};
```

which has exactly the same functionality as `plus<T>`, but avoids the template. So why was this not chosen instead? What was the logic/motivation behind the class template? (it violates the rule "do it simple if possible")

Comment: "But if this is the only reason, wouldn't it be possible to change the template argument to default to `void`?" -- Er... isn't that already the case?

Comment: In recent standards it **is** defaulted to `void`. In C++98, without `auto` and `decltype`, the specialization was almost impossible to write. So it wasn't included.

Comment: @BoPersson But even in C++98, a generalisation that did the same as `std::plus<T>` could have been implemented. So why wasn't it?

Comment: @Walter. Untrue. Consider what happens if you call it with int and long int arguments (mixed types)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Templated member functions were not allowed in early versions of C++ (even those which allowed templated classes and free functions). That meant that functors like `std::plus` had to be fully specialized, rather than deferring specialization to the operator.

Answer (score 2):

While I have already been penalized for second-guessing the reasons today, I will still dare to coin my view :)

I would assume, `std::plus` was made a template so that it could be speciailized and something else other than `+` be used for types which do not have `+` defined on them.

Comment: Given that `std::less` does in fact not have the same behaviour as `<` (for pointer types), this seems like a reasonable guess, though to be honest I'd be surprised if this is the complete reason.

Comment: AFAIK, `std::plus` is not used explicitly in any `std` algorithm, but can be used as argument. So, if you want something else, you can provide your own functor.